# Invalid characters in user name when registered

Tags: characters

I can´t register a user with ñ (español) beacause is invalid character, (i know it)

the questions are:

are there any functions that allow that?

is a server problem or a wordpress problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's Wordpress.

You could hack into wp-includes/formatting.php and comment out the contents of the sanitize_user() function.

However, I don't think that's a good idea - it may compromize your site's security, and special characters can always cause trouble...

And it's never a good idea to hack into the core (maybe you can do it also with remove_action() - but I'm not very familiar with this).

Comment: I'm seconding that. Being francophone, I have to deal with accents too. I can tell by experience. There's never good things that come out of putting an accent in your code, except if it's clear text.